# ¿Como obtener todas las filas que estén entre dos fechas?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo una base de datos en PostgreSQL donde tengo un campo fecha del tipo `character varying` con formato `DD/MM/YY`, lo que quiero obtener son todas las filas que se encuentren entre dos fechas dadas por ejemplo:

```
03/04/2017 y 07/04/2017
```

Para lo cual tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
select * from ordenes_combustible where fecha between '03/04/2017' and '07/04/2017' order by fecha desc
```

Sin embargo eso me devuelve filas de otras fechas por ejemplo me retorna fechas como

```
07/03/2017, 06/03/2017
```

saliendo del rango dado, también he intentado la consulta

```
select * from ordenes_combustible where to_date(fecha, 'DD/MM/YY') between '03/02/2017'::date and '07/02/2017'::date order by fecha desc
```

Pero en cambio me trae demasiados resultados, solo deberian aparecer 15 filas pero me trae el total de filas que es 439

**¿Cómo podría hacer para obtener los datos que necesito?**

Comment: Este tipo de problemas ilustra la importancia de usar los tipos apropiados en la base de datos.  Toma en cuenta que, aun si logras hacer la consulta convirtiendo las cadenas en fechas, pierdes la habilidad de poder mejorar el rendimiento con el uso de índices.

Comment: Si tienes razón @sstan, el problema es que es una base de datos ya existente, por lo que me toca trabajar con ella.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que al ser cadenas los verifica caracter por caracter , por lo tanto 07/03/2017 es mayor '03/04/2017', dado que el 07 es mayor que el 03, para esto debes transformar o todo en fecha o todo todo en timestamp.
Para timestamp sería algo así

```
to_timestamp('03/04/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Por lo que la consulta podría quedar así

```
SELECT * 
FROM ordenes_combustible
WHERE to_date(fecha, 'DD/MM/YY') 
  BETWEEN to_date('03/02/2017', 'DD/MM/YY') AND 
  to_date('07/02/2017', 'DD/MM/YY') 
ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

O con timestamp

```
SELECT * 
FROM ordenes_combustible
WHERE to_timestamp(fecha, 'DD/MM/YY') 
  BETWEEN to_timestamp('03/02/2017', 'DD/MM/YY') AND 
  to_timestamp('07/02/2017', 'DD/MM/YY') 
ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

Comment: Genial acabo de probarlo, funciona correctamente :)